# Replace Time Part in Date Object in Java

Tags: java, datetime

I have two date objects and I have to replace just the time part on the `newTimestamp` date object with the time in `oldTimestamp` date object:

```
Date oldTimestamp = new Date();
Date newTimestamp = new Date();
```

I am using

```
newTimestamp.withTime(oldTimestamp.getHourOfDay(), oldTimestamp.getMinuteOfHour(), oldTimestamp.getSecondOfMinute(), 000);
```

So it should get the hour, min, and sec from oldTimestamp and set it to newTimestamp right? but I don't see it setting it correctly on `newTimestamp`.

Comment: A `Date` object is not immutable. It has `setHours()/setMinutes()`, etc. I'd suggest looking at the Javadocs for Date.

Comment: @KevinO "It has setHours()/setMinutes(), etc" [which have been deprecated since Java 1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#setHours(int)).

Comment: @AndyTurner, true enough, but doesn't mean the approach won't address the particular question. Heck, I'd argue using a `Date` object itself is mostly deprecated at this point. One can go through other gyrations if desired, using Calendar, or LocalDateTime if so desired. But the question as stated may be directly addressed using the deprecated methods.

Comment: @KevinO Just because you *can* do it using deprecated methods doesn’t mean it’s good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Java 8 you can do the following

```
LocalDateTime oldDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneOffset.UTC);

// Thread.sleep(2000);

LocalDateTime replaced = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneOffset.UTC)
                             .withHour(oldDate.getHour())
                             .withMinute(oldDate.getMinute())
                             .withSecond(oldDate.getSecond())
                             .withNano(oldDate.getNano());

    System.out.printf("Old date: %s  Replaced date: %s", oldDate, replaced);
```

**Note**

If you need to work with `Date` objects, you can

```
dateObject.toInstant();
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--

This example uses Instant.now() so it is easy to test. If you uncomment line with the `Thread.sleep()` you will see the dates that are printed out will be the same even though the sleep would have caused the dates to be different.

Comment: A perfectly good solution as long as the OP does not require a `Date` object. The OP's question, as written, specifically indicates Date.

Comment: @KevinO with Date he can do `Date.toInstant()` and replace the Instant.now()

Comment: "Work with" is not equivalent to limited to. In other words, if the OP *can* use objects other than just a `Date` object, the approach is fine. If the OP *cannot* use other objects, this approach doesn't answer the question. I think the solution is great, and a good reference, but it may not directly answer the question.

Comment: @KevinO I agree with you, if he can only use Date then you already answered the question, use the deprecated setHours and setMinutes. If he is able to use other objects then he can use this solution.

Comment: A `LocalDateTime` object purposely has no time zone nor any offset. So you are throwing away valuable information. Teaching the use of `OffsetDateTime` here is more appropriate.

Comment: I am using localDateTime1.withTime(localDateTime.getHourOfDay(), localDateTime.getMinuteOfHour(), localDateTime.getSecondOfMinute(), 000); So it should get the hour, min and sec from localDateTime and set it to localDateTime1 right? but i don't see it is setting it correctly on localDateTime1.

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize that `java.util.Date` objects are always in UTC? So you won't be trading time-of-day in Montréal or Kolkata. If UTC is what you want, read on, else edit your Question.

Avoid the troublesome old legacy date-time classes, now supplanted by the java.time classes. The `java.util.Date` class is replaced by `Instant` as a point on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant instantNew = newUtilDate.toInstant();
Instant instantOld = oldUtilDate.toInstant();
```

Convert to `OffsetDateTime` objects to enable working with parts.

```
OffsetDateTime odtNew = instantNew.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
OffsetDateTime odtOld = instantOld.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

Now you can extract the date portion or the time-of-day portion and intermix.

```
LocalDate ld = odtNew.toLocalDate() ;
LocalTime lt = odtOld.toLocalTime() ;
OffsetDateTime odtMix = OffsetDateTime.of( ld , lt , ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

Best to avoid the legacy classes. But if you really need a `java.util.Date` as your result, extract an `Instant` and convert.

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( odtMix.toInstant() );
```